# Javascript | How to erase anything (divs, p's, a's, ...) which has not class ".destroy"?

Tags: javascript, document, erase

How can I make this work with pure Javascript?
Erase everything (divs, ps, as, spans, imgs, ...) in the Body section of a HTML document which has NOT the class"destroy".

PS.: Pure Javascript means: No JQuery or other frameworks..

Comment: What about the `<html>` or `<head>` elements?

Comment: <html> & <head> should be untouched - do it only in the <body> section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could walk the DOM recursively and check every node for its class. Something like this

```
function walk_the_DOM(node) {
    if (node.className && (node.className.indexOf("destroy")>-1)) {
        node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
    } else {
      node = node.firstChild;
      while (node) {
       walk_the_DOM(node);
       node = node.nextSibling;
      }
    }
 };

walk_the_DOM(document.body);
```

Answer (score 3):

Loop through `document.body.getElementsByTagName(*)`, check whether each `element.className.test(/\bdestroy\b/)`, and call `element.parentNode.removeChild(element)`.

If you're willing to use jQuery, call `$(':not(.destroy)').remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that by "Pure JavaScript" you mean "Without any third party libraries (like jQuery which is pure JS), but with the DOM APIs provided by browsers (which are usually not written in JS)" then:

1. `document.getElementsByTagName('*');`
2. Loop over it
3. Test the value of the `.className` property on each element
4. Use `foo.parentNode.removeChild(foo)`

You *will* need to refine your rules though. Otherwise you will end up removing the parent elements (including the `<html>` element) of all the nodes you want to keep (removing all their descendants in the process).

Answer (score 0):

You can walk through the DOM tree and examine the `className` property of each element. Walking the DOM tree is a lot easier than people seem to think it is:

```
var reMatch = /\bdestroy\b/;

function walk(node) { 
    var child, next, tagName;

    switch (node.nodeType) {
        case 1: // Element
            // Element, we exempt some of them; the rest,
            // check if they match
            tagName = node.tagName.toUpperCase();
            if (tagName !== "HTML" &&
                tagName != "HEAD" &&
                tagName !== "BODY" &&
                !reMatch.test(node.className)) {
                // Not exempt, doesn't have the class; remove it
                node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
                break;
            }
            /* FALL THROUGH TO */
        case 9: // Document
            // Document or Element, walk our child nodes
            for (child = node.firstChild;
                 child;
                 child = next) {
                // Important to grab the next one *before* visiting it,
                // as visiting it may remove it!
                next = child.nextSibling;
                walk(child); 
            }
            break; 
    } 
}
```

And then start things off:

```
walk(document.body);
```

...or *along those lines* (that's not tested, but it should get you going). Obviously replace those magic numbers with constants (not all implementations define them on `Node` as they should). Details in the DOM specifications: [DOM2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/), [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-DOM-Level-2-HTML-20030109/), [DOM3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/), and in the ECMAScript (JavaScript) [specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (for the regular expression).

Answer (score 0):

If you remove everything, you will remove `body`, `head` and others too. So to avoid this you can try the following code using Jquery

Try this

```
$("body").children(':not(.destroy)').remove();
```